# Android studio build error IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gradle

I just refactored my project, splitting it up into a few different modules to share some objects with the appengine backend. After moving the objects to the object library module, I'm getting this build error that i'm absolutely stumped on. Seems like it might be an android studio bug?

> Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:preDexDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source /mnt/big/Code/android-studio/MYAPP/mobile/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-13.0.0-e69ae2def885a2c3b3652240bc3ee8ea92928893.jar and destination /mnt/big/Code/android-studio/MYAPP/mobile/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-13.0.0-e69ae2def885a2c3b3652240bc3ee8ea92928893.jar must be different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clean the project and try again

Comment: Happends to everyone, includes me :(